# number to string conversion error in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, tostring

Did you ever try to convert a big number to a string in javascript?

Please try this:

```
var n = 10152557636804775;
console.log(n); // outputs 10152557636804776
```

Can you help me understand why?

Comment: `10152557636804775 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === true`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is JavaScript's number \*display\* for large numbers inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416544/why-is-javascripts-number-display-for-large-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 3):

`10152557636804775` is higher than the maximum integer number that can be *safely* represented in JavaScript (it's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) for more details.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (emphasis is mine):

> The MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant has a value of 9007199254740991. The reasoning behind that number is that **JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers** as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1.

To check if a given variable can be safely represented as an integer (without representation errors) you can use [`IsSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger):

```
var n = 10152557636804775;
console.assert(Number.isSafeInteger(n) == false);
```